# Clear specific asp.net validation group in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, requiredfieldvalidator

I can validate a specific validation group by using

```
Page_ClientValidate('validationgroup');
```

If i want to reset all validation in a page.

```
Page_ClientValidate('');
```

This works fine. 
But how to clear specific validation group ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following JavaScript to clear all the validations display

```
function clearValidationErrors() {
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < Page_Validators.length; i++) {
            Page_Validators[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
```